# Xcode says: "Identity ___ is not trusted." and won't allow me to submit my app

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, app-store-connect, xcode4.3

I've been living the nightmare of trying to submit an app to the iTunes store... The newest massive waste of time is an error message that I get when I try to validate or distribute my archive from the "organizer".

The exact message is:
[image: Identity is not trusted. Check that you have installed the WWDR intermediate certificate.]

My Xcode is version 4.3.2. I'm pretty sure my WWDR is installed, because this has never been an issue before. I also tried to re-install it just to be safe.

The most frustrating/confusing part is that I JUST submitted my app successfully two weeks ago and nothing was changed. My app was rejected for meta-data reasons. I fixed those issues, re-installed one of my plugins, and now this.

Any suggestions? Even a link to some helpful documentation would be great. I've found the Apple developer docs extremely confusing and UN-helpful.

**EDIT1:**
I think I may have gotten closer to the problem. I changed some of the build settings and now my build fails with this error:
`Code Sign error: Certificate identity 'iPhone Distribution: [my name]' appears more than once in the keychain. The codesign tool requires there only be one.` I want to fix this but I'm not clear on which code signing profile should be set where. There are different settings depending on whether I click the "project" icon or the "target" icon and each of those has four different choices. Do all of these require code signing? Can anyone give me an example of a working configuration?

**EDIT2:**
I think I maybe found the problem. There is a small note that says my Distribution profile has no provisioning portal. I've been downloading and installing new .mobileprovision files but they all say "Developer". I think just need to figure out to download a new distribution profile.

**SOLUTION:**
Thanks to some pointers from Saad (see below), I figured out what was wrong. I was using the auto-select option for code signing, and the only distribution profile had an invalid provisioning profile. This happened very quietly, and I'm not sure why. I only noticed it when I went back into the provisioning portal to create a new distribution profile. After installing this, everything works.

Comment: Go to Organizer and see what profile says ! It is issue with provisioning profile only.

Comment: I'm not sure how to do this, but when I click the tab called "devices"  I see three provisioning profiles and they all say "valid". Is this what I'm looking for?

Comment: Yes there are 4 columns. Name/Expiration Date/Portal Team/Status. Are you sure the profile you selected does not have anything to say in status column ?

Comment: Yes. There was one profile with an error icon, but I deleted it. Now there are three profiles, which all say "Valid Profile" under status.

Comment: So you need to download that profile again if you want to submit application along with that profile. Or you can proceed again with existing profiles to submit and that error won't come again.

Comment: I don't think I was using that problematic profile. I have three more profiles that appear valid. So I'd like to proceed with one of those. However, I need to figure out the code-signing settings so I can do the build again. Please take a look at the second screenshot that I added above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your provisioning profile is not properly set

Comment: I'm trying to check set the profiles correctly, but I'm not sure how. When I set the options for code signing, there are 4 different options which I can change independently. How do I know which should be which? I'm adding another screenshot above.

Comment: sett all of them according to ur distribution profile of appstore. both in projct n target

Comment: @Saad: can you explain that a bit more? I'm trying very hard to do what you described, but at the moment I'm just guessing because I don't know what the correct settings are.

Comment: i'm saying that all the code signing sections u see, set them to ur profile, which wud be a valid profile for appstore distribution.

Comment: So all the same? All four options can be the same profile? I have almost 8 different choices when I click the option to set code signing.

Comment: and in your pic u have written confustion which one. i said it you have to do it for both of them. target as well as projct

Comment: @Saad. Thanks very much. This helps... I think I'm very close to fixing this. Please see my most recent edit. I think I need a new distribution profile (I've been adding developer profiles).

Comment: nope. for appstore submission u need only appstore distribution. go to ios provisioning center, then distribution and then again appstore, and make profile there. note that there are two portions of appstore distribution. one is adhoc and one is appstore, you must have to select the appstore option. tell me if u see again any prblm

Comment: SUCCESS!!
I went into the provisioning portal and there I learned that my distribution profile was marked as invalid. I'm not sure why this happened, but I created a new one and now it works! Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

> `Code Sign error: Certificate identity 'iPhone Distribution: [my
>   name]' appears more than once in the keychain. The codesign tool
>   requires there only be one.`

Open Applications > Utilities > Keychain Access and search for your Distribution certificate.  Sometimes the Xcode Organizer decides to generate a new certificate for you and invalidates your old one, but does not remove it from your keychain.  Remove the expired/older certificate and quit/re-launch Xcode (make a backup first, in case, by dragging to Desktop or Exporting).  That should at least clear up part of your problem.

As for the provisioning profile, if that still is a problem, I'd manually go into the iOS development center and download the App Store Distribution Provision Profile for your app, removing all other provisioning profiles, until you figure this out.  Quitting and relaunching Xcode when dealing with certs/provisioning profiles is something I've always had to do.

Comment: Very good suggestion. I just solved this by doing essentially just what you said. I think the moral of the story is: "When in doubt, download a new provisioning profile."

Answer (score 0):

project identifier and your profile identifier must match